Installing water pump for water pressure tank without safety ground wire
I've got a friend living in a house in The Philippines that used to have a water pump installed due to low water pressure. There are only two wires (no earth wire) and there are no automatic circuit breakers in the very old circuit box. But the "water pump" is detailed on the circuit box diagram.
Recently a HVAC guy installed an aircon. He commented on how old the circuit box was. I'm a bit concerned if he even grounded it with an earth wire.
My friend wants to install a new water pressure tank. Would installing a Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter outlet suffice in this case for that task?
Is this a more serious issue perhaps needing to replace the circuit box and wiring?
Asking here for general advice because I'm wary of trusting electricians over there.



Whatever do you mean "no automatic breakers" and what particular 3rd world country are we discussing, which has a bearing on how it's likely to be arranged. The pump won't run without Neutral unless it's one of the very few places that (approximately) follows the US split-phase scheme where the pump would get two different hots as hot/live is not 240V to ground/earth. Which the breaker panel does resemble...

@Ecnerwal Sorry, I meant "no earth wire". Can only see two black wires sticking out. The country is The Philippines and they use 240V. By "automatic breaker" I mean it will shut off to prevent fires. Which is what concerns me.

Those look like circuit breakers to me, which is as "automatic" as it gets, so I too am confused by that statement. But, yes, if a 240V GFCI is available it can provide the same kind of electrical safety as a ground wire (better in some ways) and would be a good idea.

@keshlam I'm from Europe and we do not have these types of breakers. It's unclear to me whether they are intended to be moved manually or will shut off automatically (e.g to prevent electrocutions in showers). Would a GFCI breaker fit in that circuit box or would I have to install a GFCI outlet near the water pump?

Circuit breakers shut off automatically when excessive power is drawn, to prevent wires from overheating and starting a file. That's their whole reason for existing. You have shown us a panel full of circuit breakers. No problem there. The only issue is the absent safety ground.

GFCIs can be installed either by replacing a breaker with one that includes GFCI function (requires being competent/legal to work inside the breaker box, which you aren't), or by replacing the outlet with one that includes a GFCI function (easier to do; install a proper electrical box where the wires come out if the wall, install a GFCI into that box, connect the pump to the load terminals of the GFCI or just put a plug on its wires and plug it in).

Apparently (no personal experience) the Phillipines is weird, because they were using US-type split-phase 120V to ground some time ago and have transitioned (or are tranisioning??) to Euro-spec 230-240V to ground. The breakers in that panel will handle 240V to ground just fine, but things might get complicated, depending where on the "transition" timeline things have been done. Harper seems to be familiar with it if he drops by. The breakers are automatic, however they are not (in addition to overcurrent) the type that trips on a ground fault or arc fault. Retrofit may be impossible.

...continuing. The panel maker may well make GFCI and AFCI breakers, but if the panel is now running 240V to ground & neutral they will not work, as the power supply for those assumes 120V to ground & neutral, typically. So going to a new Euro-spec type panel you'd recognize might be the only practical way to add those features. That might also lead to re-wiring the whole house; both tend to be expensive jobs. It's possible that pump was in 120V to ground/earth time and the supply may have been changed since it was removed (or it was removed becasue the supply changed)

@Ecnerwal I was under the impression that in the US you use two live wires to achieve 240 volts. Then for 120 volts you use one live and one neutral. Also, got some more info. It seemed the HVAC guy installed the A/C using the "water pump" breaker and after a while it kept tripping constantly, so an electrician had to come by and draw a new wire directly to the circuit box and he put the wire on the wall leading into it, instead of using the existing system despite there being a few unused breaker slots. The A/C also has a breaker installed right by the compressor unit.
